# How to use the mouseover and mouseout events to change background color of all of the generated divs/grid-items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am completing the "etch-a-sketch" challenge as part of TOP curriculum. I have successfully created a 16 x 16 grid utilizing JS DOM manipulation and CSS grid. The second part of my problem is to make each individual grid-item/cell change background color on hover. I chose to use JS with the mouseover Eventlistener, but also saw the CSS: hover Selector as a viable option when googling for information.

I have created 2 functions `overing` and `outing` to change the background color of the grid-item on hover using the "mouseover" event listener. The functions only work on the first generated cell/grid-item. May someone please explain how I can get my overing and outing functions to work on all grid-items.[only 1st grid-item working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqb3g.png)

```js
//Function and call to generate 16x16 grid of divs. 
document.getElementById("container");

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows)
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols)
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};
makeGrid(16, 16);
//Function to change background color of individual "grid-item" on hover.
document.querySelector('.grid-item').addEventListener('mouseover', overing);
document.querySelector('.grid-item').addEventListener('mouseout', outing);

function overing(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  console.log('mouseenter div');
}

function outing(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  console.log('mouseleave div');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sketch-Book</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etchStyles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="etchScript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(..)` returns the first element that matches the selector. To retrieve all of them, use [`document.querySelectorAll(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and loop through the list.

Comment: Just bind the vent when you make the element... `cell.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: Code like `container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows)` in the JS really kind of defeats the purpose of the CSS and makes your code too-tightly integrated IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Titus is right. But since you are using javascript to create each DOM node, you can exploit this fact to attach event listeners at creation time. Ex:

```js
const overing = (ev) => {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  //console.log('mouseenter div');
};

const outing = (ev) => {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  //console.log('mouseleave div');
}

const makeGrid = (rows, cols) => {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows)
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols)
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    cell.classList.add('grid-item');
    
    //  attach listeners here since you have a reference to the DOM node
    cell.addEventListener("mouseover", overing);
    cell.addEventListener("mouseout", outing);
    
    container.appendChild(cell);
  };
};

makeGrid(16, 16);
```

```css
section {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use css [`:hover`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.php), here is an example with a 3x3 grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 30vh) / repeat(3, 30vw);
  background-color: white;
  height: 94vh;
  width: 94vw;
  grid-row-gap:1vh;
  grid-column-gap:1vw;
}

.grid_element {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.grid_element:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
  <div class="grid_element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers support template ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template so lets' use that instead of manually creating an element so out code can be smaller - especially if you add more content to each "cell" such as a set of spans, divs etc.

You can determine what you want for event handlers but you can add those right in the same loop when creating them.

NOTE: Probably want to create a new DIV just to append all the NEW items to before hitting the DOM and appending them all at once but I will leave that exercise to you as outside the question scope.

```js
function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const template = document.getElementById("grid-cell-template");
  for (let c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    const cloneCell = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    const newItem = cloneCell.querySelector(".grid-item");
    newItem.textContent = (c + 1);
    newItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterEventHandler);
    newItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEventHandler);
    newItem.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverEventHandler);
    container.appendChild(newItem);
  }
}
makeGrid(16, 16);

function mouseEnterEventHandler(event) {
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#FF000022';
}

function mouseLeaveEventHandler(event) {
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
  event.target.style.borderColor = "#000000";
}

function mouseOverEventHandler(event) {
  event.target.style.borderColor = "#00FF00";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --grid-cols: 16;
  --grid-rows: 16;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <template id="grid-cell-template">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </template>
</body>
```